# formula that if a cell contains a number in a string of text it displays it in another cell

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula in excel that if a cell contains a number in a string of text it displays that number ignoring the other text.

So if A1 contains the text "license12M", the formula in A2 displays "12".

The text in the string will relate to a lot of products, but the number will be either 12,24,36,48 or 60.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If it's only one of those 5 numbers you could search explicitly for those, e.g. with this formula

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/FIND({12,24,36,48,60},A1),{12,24,36,48,60}),"No match")`

Answer (score 0):

To extract **any** embedded number from text, try the *array formula*:

```
=MID(SUMPRODUCT(--MID("01"&A1,SMALL((ROW($1:$300)-1)*ISNUMBER(-MID("01"&A1,ROW($1:$300),1)),ROW($1:$300))+1,1),10^(300-ROW($1:$300))),2,300)
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.